# jquery-ui buttonset click event doesn't seem to change the checked state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am using a jquery-ui buttonset with 2 radio buttons for yes/no input.

```
var yesInput = document.createElement("input");
yesInput.type = "radio";
$(yesInput).attr('id', "njs1");
$(yesInput).prop('checked', this._data);

var noInput = document.createElement("input");
noInput.type = "radio";
$(noInput).attr('id', "njs2");
$(noInput).prop('checked', !this._data);
```

I am calling a change event, on these buttons and in the handling function trying to detect whether the checked button is clicked. `buttonSet` is the div that is made into a `buttonset()`.

`$("input[type=radio]", buttonSet).change(checkHandler);`

```
var data= $("input[type=radio]", buttonSet).eq(0).is(':checked');
```

In such a situation, I am expecting that if the second button is clicked, data should return false. My understanding is when I check a radio, it's html is modified to add `checked`.

However, irrespective of what is being called, data is always `true`.

What am I doing wrong? How to get the correct value?

Edit:

[Example fiddle](http://jsbin.com/wuhozayevo/edit?html,js,output)

As you can see, I can click on No and still have Yes checked. Since it is a radio, I expect it to behave that way

Comment: Can you provide an example of you code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wuhozayevo/edit?html,js,output

I am not sure why the buttonset is not rendered as it should be, but that's not the concern since it most likely is specific to jsbin. 

As you can see, I can click on No and still have Yes checked. Since it is a radio, I expect it to behave that way.

Comment: Couple of issues:
1) radio input element should have a `name` attribute with the same value so they are linked, to make sure only `yes` or `no` can be selected.
2) I'm seeing a mixed usage of vanilla js and jQuery code; What is the purpose of vanillajs in your code?
3) Not sure what `$(buttonSet).buttonset();` does. It this some jquery plugin?
4) You are loading both jquery 1.x and 2.x in the example.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the reference to the old jquery library.

I am using vanilla js just because, I have a function that passes the container div which holds the buttonset as an argument. This is why I wanted to keep it as separate as possible. 

The official jquery-ui documentation suggests using `$(buttonSet).buttonset();`  and shows the same in the examples. https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/#method-option

Comment: @chimurai After the changes, it looks as it should. But then, the same issue of both being checked at the same time (Even after adding a `name` attribute) is still there.

Comment: Both input elements should have to same name attribute, such as: `"name": "togglebutton"`. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change to checked state of the input element, you'll have to use to `.prop()`

Set to checked:

`$( "input" ).prop( "checked", true );`

Set to unchecked:

`$( "input" ).prop( "checked", false );`

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Previous to jQuery 1.6 `.attr` did change both the html attribute and dom property.

As of v1.6 this behavior has been changed.

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

**Update**

Both radio inputs should have the exact same value to group them together.

`$(yesInput).attr('id', "njs1");
    $(yesInput).attr('name', "toggle");  // << shared name
    $(noInput).attr('id', "njs2");
    $(yesInput).attr('name', "toggle");  // << shared name`

Comment: I updated to the latest jquery and switched to prop, still the same issue is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using jQuery's way of creating elements?
use click events for radio buttons.

```
$('<input/>').attr({type: "radio", "id": "njs1"})
.prop("checked", !this._data)
.click(checkHandler);
```

Comment: Updated the code as suggested. Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: try using removeAttr("checked") for unchecking.

Comment: But, I am not unchecking in my handler. I am setting an initial state while defining the inputs. 
Doesn't jquery take care of that?